# ¿ Como detectar idioma del usuario y que haga una cosa u otra?

Tags: java, android, idioma

Simplemente necesito saber si es inglés vaya a url2 y si es español url . Tengo unos layout con strings en español y en inglés y sé usarlos para que salga dependiendo del idioma del usario, pero al ser una URL, no soy capaz de hacer que vaya a una URL u a otra.

He intentado poner una cadena y comparándola o asignarle números pero nada, no soy capaz. La solución sería if(es ingles) { vaya a url2} si no (español}

`public class Competidores extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {`

```
WebView appWeb;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.four_tab, container, false);


    String url = " https://rudeboysapp.wordpress.com/";
    String url2 = " https://rudeboysappenglish.wordpress.com/";

  if(l7 == "es") {

        appWeb = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        //Habilitamos el javaScript y el zoom
        appWeb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        // appWeb.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        //Cargamos el enlace definido
        appWeb.loadUrl(url);
        //Este método es para que el navegador se quede en nuestra aplicación
        appWeb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return false;
            }
        });

    }else {


        appWeb = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        //Habilitamos el javaScript y el zoom
        appWeb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        // appWeb.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        //Cargamos el enlace definido
        appWeb.loadUrl(url2);
        //Este método es para que el navegador se quede en nuestra aplicación
        appWeb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return false;
            }
        });

    }




    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes de recoger el idioma del sistema usando el objeto Locale y su método getDefault():

```
Locale.getDefault().toString();
```

Según lo que te de, será un idioma u otro. Por ejemplo, inglés americano es "en_US" mientras que inglés británico es "en_EN" y español de España es "es_ES"... y así sucesivamente. Si te fijas, siempre las dos primeras siglas son el idioma y las dos siguientes detrás del "_" son el país.

Si solo te interesa el idioma sin importar el país, tienes el método getLanguage():

```
    String l7 = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage(); // es
```

Este objeto también tiene otros métodos que te pueden ser útiles como:

```
    String l1 = Locale.getDefault().getCountry(); // español
    String l2 = Locale.getDefault().getDisplayCountry(); // España
    String l3 = Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage(); // español
    String l4 = Locale.getDefault().getDisplayName();        // español (España)
    String l5 = Locale.getDefault().getDisplayVariant(); //""
    String l6 = Locale.getDefault().getISO3Language(); //spa
    String l7 = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage(); // es
    String l8 = Locale.getDefault().toString(); // es_ES
```

Comment: Está bien, pero una vez pongo lo de string l7, como hago para poner si es español hago una cosa si es ingles otra? **if( que pongo aqui dentro)** ?? if( l7 == "en_US") ?

Comment: @RFMvs debes realizar una comparación de lo que devuelve el getLanguge con "es" sino lanzas la url en ingles

Comment: si, he probado "en", voy a probar "es".

Comment: no me lo coge , estoy poniendo.. ( mira actualizacion arriba) y siempre va al ``else`` no entra al ``if``

Comment: vale, reo que ya esta solucionado, he puesto .equals y si que me lo coge.